# Error about TMP_DIR space using parallel program

Tags: linux

I am using parallel for freebayes to call variants using,

```
TMPDIR=/path/tmp freebayes-parallel <(fasta_generate_regions.py genome.fasta.fai 100000) 36 \
-f genome.fasta -L $bam_list.txt > freebayes.vcf
```

But it gives error:

```
parallel: Error: Output is incomplete. Cannot append to buffer file tmp. Is the disk full?
parallel: Error: Change $TMPDIR with --tmpdir or use --compress.
```

I found some other posts where they suggested to change the tmp where space is available. I am not sure how to do that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, have you tried to `Change $TMPDIR with --tmpdir or use --compress`...? You could presumably say for example `--tmpdir /some/dir/with/lots/of/space`

Comment: I tried do the same as: freebayes-parallel --tmpdir /path/tmp <(fasta_generate_regions.py genome.fasta.fai 100000) 36 \
-f genome.fasta -L $bam_list.txt > freebayes.vcf. But I got the same error. I am not sure if I used the command at right place.